# Radio button OnCheckedChangeListener error inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am facing some problem when calling onCheckedCahngedListener inside fragment on radio group app crashes.
when clicking on any item inside radio group the app crashed.

fragment_sell.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication.SellFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RadioButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/first"
            >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sApartment"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:button="@drawable/apartment"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:onClick="apartment"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0.2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/vertical" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sBuilder"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:button="@drawable/house"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:onClick="house"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0.2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/vertical" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sPlot"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:button="@drawable/land"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:onClick="land"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0.2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/vertical" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sHouse"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:button="@drawable/builder"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:onClick="builder"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0.2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/vertical" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sStudioApartment"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:button="@drawable/farmhouse"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:onClick="farmhouse"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0.2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/vertical" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sFarmHouse"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:button="@drawable/serviceapartment"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:onClick="servicedapartment"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0.2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/vertical" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sServicedApartment"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:button="@drawable/studioapartment"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:onClick="studioapartment"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0.2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/vertical" />


        </RadioGroup>



    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

SellFragment.java

```
public class SellFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

private RadioGroup mRadioGroup1;
private RadioButton mapartment;
private RadioButton mBuilder;
private RadioButton mplot;
private RadioButton mHouse;
private RadioButton mStudioApartment;
private RadioButton mFarmhouse;
private RadioButton mServicedApartment;

private Spinner city;
private View layout;

public static SellFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    SellFragment fragment = new SellFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sell, container, false);


    mRadioGroup1=(RadioGroup) layout.findViewById(R.id.RadioButton1);
    mapartment=(RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.sApartment);
    mBuilder=(RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.sBuilder);
    mplot=(RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.sPlot);
    mHouse=(RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.sHouse);
    mStudioApartment=(RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.sStudioApartment);
    mFarmhouse=(RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.sFarmHouse);
    mServicedApartment=(RadioButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.sServicedApartment);

    mRadioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


        @Override

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if (checkedId == R.id.sApartment) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sell Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } else if (checkedId == R.id.sBuilder) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sell Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
            else if (checkedId == R.id.sPlot) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sell Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (checkedId == R.id.sHouse) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sell Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (checkedId == R.id.sStudioApartment) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sell Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (checkedId == R.id.sFarmHouse) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sell Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else if (checkedId == R.id.cServicedApartment) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sell Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

    });

    return  layout;
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}}
```

Logcat:

```
03-23 02:50:57.703    4697-4697/com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.syedsaadali.myapplication, PID: 4697
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method apartment(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton with id 'cApartment'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `<RadioButton ... android:onClick="apartment"/>` In the `XML` But any method `apartment` was not created in `Activity`.

To resolve this Either remove that `onClick` attribute *(if note needed)* OR create a method `apartment` in java as well like

```
public void apartment(View view){

}
```

You can directly click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in `onClick` attribute of `XML` to get the hint of resolving this error by creating method.